# How can I refund purchases?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I had a lot of coins then my brother bought like everything so I need to know how to restore all my purchases and still get all my coins back.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 6):

If your brother spent the coins on stuff, then I'm afraid you're stuck with the items he bought, and will have to re-earn your coins.  There's no way to "take back" purchases.

Comment: As they say in stores, "no returns".